# Как можно провести сравнение в цикле?

Tags: python

Есть такой код. Нужно провести сравнение, чтобы все строки были равны соответствующим. Можно сделать это как-то красивее, в цикле или что-то типа того? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
qs_cart = ECart.objects.filter(user_id=obj.user_id)
                qs_delivery = EOrderDelivery.objects.filter(order_id__in=qs_cart.values('order_id'))
                for idx, obj in enumerate(qs_delivery):
                    if idx == 0:
                        fields = ['city', 'country', 'flat', 'house', 'region', 'street', 'postal_code']
                        obj_ok = obj
                        id_ok = qs_cart[0].order_id
                    else:
                        if (getattr(obj, fields[0]) == getattr(obj_ok, fields[0])) and (
                                getattr(obj, fields[1]) == getattr(obj_ok, fields[1])) and (
                                getattr(obj, fields[2]) == getattr(obj_ok, fields[2])) and (
                                getattr(obj, fields[3]) == getattr(obj_ok, fields[3])) and (
                                getattr(obj, fields[4]) == getattr(obj_ok, fields[4])) and (
                                getattr(obj, fields[5]) == getattr(obj_ok, fields[5])) and (
                                getattr(obj, fields[6]) == getattr(obj_ok, fields[6])):
                            qs_cart.update(order_id=id_ok)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так:

```
fields = ['city', 'country', 'flat', 'house', 'region', 'street', 'postal_code']

# формируем список значений по полям
obj_data = [getattr(obj, name) for name in fields]
obj_ok_data = [getattr(obj_ok, name) for name in fields]

# сравниваем 
if all([i[0] == i[1] for i in zip(obj_data, obj_ok_data)]):
    print()
```

или даже так:

```
fields = ['city', 'country', 'flat', 'house', 'region', 'street', 'postal_code']

# формируем список значений по полям
obj_data = [getattr(obj, name) for name in fields]
obj_ok_data = [getattr(obj_ok, name) for name in fields]

# сравниваем 
if obj_data == obj_ok_data:
    print()
```

а если мучать первый вариант, то:

```
fields = ['city', 'country', 'flat', 'house', 'region', 'street', 'postal_code']

# формируем список значений по полям и сравниваем 
if all(getattr(obj, name) == getattr(obj_ok, name) for name in fields):
    print()
```

наверное последний вариант самый красивый

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!